# Can I use the name column in python?

Tags: python, sql

I would like to be able to use my SQL table in python.
I managed to connect and access my table using the code.

I would like to know if it was possible to retrieve the column names in my code.

I already have my colomns:

```
ACTION    |    MANAGER
123             XYZ
456             ABC
```

```
PersonnesQuery = "SELECT........"
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute(PersonnesQuery)
records_Personnes = cursor.fetchall()


for row in records_Personnes:
   if (row["MANAGER"] == "XYZ"):
                ..................
   elif (row["MANAGER"] == "ABC"):
                ................
```

the way quoted does not seem to work. However, it works with the number, for example row[0]. But I would like by column name

Comment: @glibdud thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a field by key, in this case "MANAGER", row should be a dict. But due to the fact that you can access row by index, row is type list.
Meaning you can't access by key when using .fetchall() because it returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the pymysql library, in which case there is a specific kind of cursor called a [DictCursor](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.DictCursor). This will return the results as a dictionary rather than a list.

```
cursor = mydb.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute(PersonnesQuery)
records_Personnes = cursor.fetchall()
```